# Should client or server send ping message?

Tags: javascript, websocket

I always thought it's the responsibility of the client to send a `ping` message to make sure server is available or handle disconnection in a proper way.

But lately I read an article where the initiator of `ping` messages is server side. So, server sends `ping` and client should respond with `pong` if it can.

What's the more general universal approach and why?

Comment: It should really be implemented two-way IMO, from server - to know which client sockets are dead and free the memory, from client - to know that the connection is up.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [websocket RFC  - examples](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455#section-5.7), it shows Unmasked Ping request (`Ping` frame) and masked Ping response (`Pong` frame) where Ping is from server and Pong is from client.

But, [Ping](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455#section-5.5.2) and [Pong](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455#section-5.5.3) sections mention "endpoint" which can be either client or server.

So, client and server both should be able to send `Ping` frame and the other party should reply with `Pong` frame.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really answer the question as it probably depends on the case.
But how can the server knows who send `ping` to if the client never sent anything before ?

**In my opinion** it's the client who need to start the "conversation".

I see you mentionned `websocket` in tags. `websocket` (server)  needs to receive a first message from the client before starting to send the expected data to this client.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [discussion](https://groups.google.com/g/vertx/c/Ws7py-vUMNk), seems like server should be the one to send ping, while clients respond with pong.